# FreeBSD 12.x: rsync a specific folder to my destination folder

Tags: rsync, freebsd

as above

I think it's best explained with an example.

```
/mnt/source/source-folder
  -> sfolder1
  -> sfolder2 
  -> sfolder3
  -> sfolder4
```

The "sfolder" contains 10s of folders and 100s of files inside them.

I want to copy "sfolder2 and its contents" to /mnt/destination/destination-folder.

I tried

```
rsync -nriv --stats --include "sfolder2" --exclude "*" /mnt/source/source-folder/ /mnt/destination/destination-folder/

rsync -nriv --stats --include "sfolder2*" --exclude "*" /mnt/source/source-folder/ /mnt/destination/destination-folder/

rsync -nriv --stats --include "*sfolder2*" --exclude "*" /mnt/source/source-folder/ /mnt/destination/destination-folder/
```

and in all cases, stats report that only the "sfolder2" folder was transferred and the 10s of folders and 100s of files inside "sfolder2" was ignored.

What am I doing wrong?

My real aim is to copy multiple folders (from my sample folder setup above, sfolder2 and sfolder4) from the source to my destination. I'm only using 1 folder for now while testing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You excluded "everything everywhere" with `*` and included `sfolder2` which only transfers a file or directory `sfolder2` in the transfer root directory.

Instead you could use `/*` to only exclude files relative to the source directory.
This means if e.g. `/sfolder3` is excluded, then all files inside `/sfolder3` are also excluded since the parent directory is excluded.

Using `/sfolder2/` makes it explicit that the directory is relative to the source directory (`/` at start) and is a directory (`/` at end). I also replaced `-r` with `-a` (archive mode) which includes `-r`:

```
rsync -naiv --stats --include='/sfolder2/' --exclude='/*' \
 /mnt/source/source-folder/ /mnt/destination/destination-folder/
```

To include `sfolder2` and `sfolder4`:

```
rsync -naiv --stats --include='/sfolder2/' --include='/sfolder4/' --exclude='/*' \
 /mnt/source/source-folder/ /mnt/destination/destination-folder/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use relative paths, thereby avoiding all the `--include` and `--exclude` complications. Here, the `--relative` (`-R`) flag tells `rsync` to maintain the source paths at the destination. The `/./` in the source marks the start of the path to be maintained (without it the entire path would be kept)

```
rsync --dry-run -aivR --stats /mnt/source/source-folder/./sfolder2/ /mnt/destination/destination-folder
```

This will copy `sfolder2` and its contents to `/mnt/destination/destination-folder/sfolder2`.

To copy multiple folders (`sfolder2` and `sfolder4`) you can use multiple source paths. Like this if your shell handles braced groups `{x,y}`,

```
rsync --dry-run -aivR --stats /mnt/source/source-folder/./sfolder{2,4}/ /mnt/destination/destination-folder
```

or this otherwise

```
rsync --dry-run -aivR --stats /mnt/source/source-folder/./sfolder2/ /mnt/source/source-folder/./other4/ /mnt/destination/destination-folder
```

(As an aside, rather than using just `--recursive` (`-r`) for copying a tree of files, either use `--archive` (`-a`) instead or add `--times` (`-t`) to help `rsync` with optimising future copies of the same files. In my example I've used `-a`; you could use `-rt` if you want to avoid copying ownerships and permissions.)